# WPF TreeView.SelectedContainer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a TreeView control.  It has a SelectedItemChanged event handler.  In this event handler, the sender parameter comes in as a TreeView.  When expanding and investigating the datatips for sender, it displays a property 'SelectedContainer'
as 
((System.Windows.Controls.TreeView)(sender)).SelectedContainer

I can not find this property anywhere.  So where does it come from?
Is this property accessible to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's internal.  From Reflector:

```
    internal TreeViewItem SelectedContainer
    {
        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
        get
        {
            return this._selectedContainer;
        }
    }
```

You should be able to get the container from the ItemContainerGenerator:

```
    var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(treeView.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Note: the ItemContainerGenerator is not doing a recursive search, but only looks in the top layer. There's a recursive extension method in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/silverlight/en-us/84cd3a27-6b17-48e6-8f8a-e5737601fdac/treeviewitemcontainergeneratorcontainerfromitem-returns-null?forum=silverlightnet